# NGINX + Drupal installed in subfolder on linux server

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, drupal

I'm trying to configure the server like this have this accessible addresses:

```
domain.com/webmail (webmail app)
domain.com/app (node.js app)
domain.com/mailadmin (mail administration app)
domain.com/site (drupal website)
```

My Root diretory is `/var/www`

which has the following directories:

```
/var/www/webmail
/var/www/app
/var/www/postfixadmin
/var/www/site
```

I have tried several configurations and none of them worked (some worked partially, showing the homepage or showing all pages but without any CSS styles)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two spending all day on this. I finally found a fully working solution:

1. First you need change the `location /` (Catch all) so it doesn't try to fetch subdirectories
2. Then you need to create a `location /subfolder_name/` for each app you want to have served
3. Finally you need to configure the drupal location and a rewrite so it catches the requests of `/drupal_subfolder/` and rewrites it for the Drupal router.

So here's the code:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location /app/ {
         // reverse proxy configuration of a node.js app
         ...
    }

    location /webmail/ {

    }

    location /mailadmin/ {

    }

    location @drupal_rewrite {
            rewrite ^/site/(.*)$ /site/index.php?$1;
    }

    location /site/ {
            try_files $uri @drupal_rewrite;
    }
```

In my configuration (above) only the `location /app/` and `location /site/` blocks have content.

Hope it helps someone. :)

(I used: ubuntu + nginx + drupal 8.2)